# find limit of $a_n=\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}+\frac{1}{(n+2)^2}+...+\frac{1}{(2n)^2}$

Tags: calculus, analysis

finding limit of $a_n=\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}+\frac{1}{(n+2)^2}+...+\frac{1}{(2n)^2}$

I know that i have to use Stolz Cesaro theorem, but the problem is that i need second sequence.

Answer (score 4):

The limit is $0$:

$\displaystyle\frac1{(n+k)^2}\le\frac1{n^2}$ for $1\le k\le n$, so $\displaystyle 0\le a_n\le \frac{n}{n^2}=\frac1n\to0$.

Let me add two remarks: First of all, $\sum_n a_n$ diverges, because if fact $a_n$ grows like $1/n$: $\displaystyle\frac1{(n+k)^2}\ge\frac1{(2n)^2}$ for $1\le k\le n$, so $\displaystyle a_n\ge \frac{n}{(2n)^2}=\frac1{4n}$.

Second, the above suggests to study $\lim_{n\to\infty}n a_n$. Recognizing this as a Riemann sum is the key: Note that 
 $$ n\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{(n+k)^2}=\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{(1+k/n)^2}, $$
which we should recognize as a Riemann sum for $\displaystyle \int_0^1\frac1{(1+x)^2}\,dx$, so the two expressions coincide when $n\to\infty$, and we see that 
 $$\lim_{n\to\infty}na_n=\int_0^1\frac1{(1+x)^2}\,dx=\left.\frac{-1}{1+x}\right|_0^1=\frac12. $$
To illustrate the rate of convergence, [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/) evaluates $na_n$ when $n=200$, as $0.498128645813151$; when $n=2000$, as $0.499812536458331$; and when $n=20000$, as $0.499981250364583$.

Comment: thank you. I haven't thought, that it might be so easy.

Comment: Make sure this is what is being asked, as opposed to determining the convergence of $\sum a_n$.

Comment: elegant one. nice answer.

Comment: @Kacper If you really like the answer ,you may consider to accept it by clicking the "right" sign on the left hand side of the answer as It will reduce the number of unaccepted answers.

Comment: (It would be nice to have a "calculus-free" argument for $na_n\to1/2$.)

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$S=\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}+\frac{1}{(n+2)^2}+...+\frac{1}{(2n)^2}=\sum_{1\le r\le 2n}\frac1{r^2}-\sum_{1\le r\le n}\frac1{r^2}$$

Putting $2n=m$ in the first sum $$S=4\sum_{1\le r\le m}\frac1{r^2}-\sum_{1\le r\le n}\frac1{r^2}$$

Now use [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8337/different-methods-to-compute-sum-limits-n-1-infty-frac1n2)

Comment: but answer is seems zero. are we getting zero here?

Comment: @GA316, no.  I am trying to figure out the mistake.

Comment: one small doubt. are you summing over r?

Comment: @GA316, yes, from $n+1$ to $2n$

Comment: I cant find where is the mistake really. curious to know.

Comment: @GA316, I'm seriously eager to know the same:)

Comment: @labbhattacharjee You can't replace $m = 2n$, since you're summing over all $1 \leq r \leq 2n$, not just the even ones.

Answer (score 1):

$$a_n=\frac{1}{n^2}\left( \frac{1}{(1+\frac1n)^2}+\frac{1}{(1+\frac2n)^2}+...+\frac{1}{(1+\frac{n}n)^2} \right)=\frac{1}{n}\left[\frac{1}{n}\left( \frac{1}{(1+\frac1n)^2}+\frac{1}{(1+\frac2n)^2}+...+\frac{1}{(1+\frac{n}n)^2} \right)\right]$$

Now, apply  S-C to

$$a_n=\frac{ \left( \frac{1}{(1+\frac1n)^2}+\frac{1}{(1+\frac2n)^2}+...+\frac{1}{(1+\frac{n}n)^2} \right)  }{n^2}$$

**But this is an overkill**, it is easy to see that the top is $\leq 1+1+1..+1=n$.

**P.S.**

$$\frac{1}{n}\left( \frac{1}{(1+\frac1n)^2}+\frac{1}{(1+\frac2n)^2}+...+\frac{1}{(1+\frac{n}n)^2} \right)$$ 
is a Riemann sum, thus convergent, and $\frac{1}{n}$ converges to $0$.

Alternately, if you don't know integrals,apply S-C to

$$a_n=\frac{ \left( \frac{1}{(1+\frac1n)^2}+\frac{1}{(1+\frac2n)^2}+...+\frac{1}{(1+\frac{n}n)^2} \right)  }{n^2}$$

Comment: I had wondered when the Stolz–Cesàro theorem was going to show up. Do you see a way of adapting its use to verify that $na_n\to1/2$?

Comment: @AndresCaicedo Since $na_n$ is a Riemann sum, I don't see how one can use SC to calculate the integral.  Maybe if one sues SC for something like $2^na_{2^n}$.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve by another method . This must be interesting to you.

Hint : $lt_{n \rightarrow \infty} $ $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} f(\frac{k}{n})$ $ =  $ $\int_0^1 f(x) dx$ where $f$ is in $C[0,1]$

Comment: thanks but i'm in highschool and i  haven't had integrals yet.

Comment: ok. I will give detailed answer. some time it may help you.